# Запятая после "это значит, (что)"

Tags: пунктуация

Это значит завтра пораньше надо будет встретиться — значит выступает в роли связки и запятая не требуется?

Comment: Можно двоеточие поставить. Это говорит: завтра пораньше надо будет встретиться.

Comment: @user190920 С двоеточием здесь плохо звучит (интонация понижения и длительная пауза).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Розенталь:
Тире ставится перед словами *это, это есть, значит, это значит, вот*, присоединяющими к подлежащему сказуемое, выраженное существительным в именительном падеже, личным местоимением или **глаголом в неопределенной форме**. Например:
*Коммунизм — это есть Советская власть плюс электрификация всей страны* (Ленин).  *Нравиться — это дело юношей* (Тургенев).
*Быть коммунистом — значит дерзать, думать, хотеть, сметь* (Маяковский).
*Аврал — это значит общая работа, когда одной вахты мало и нужны все руки* (Гончаров).
*Подхалюзины и Чичиковы — вот сильные практические характеры «темного царства»*
(Добролюбов).
*Техника — это мы* (Федин).

Здесь самостоятельное предложение ("это значит" не после тире, а в самом начале), потому что присоединяется не сказуемое, а простое предложение (которое требует постановки запятой).

Пример:
*Это значит, он придёт домой и сделает уроки.* || Кто-нибудь хочет убрать запятую перед этим простым предложением? Может, Виктор?
*Завтра пораньше надо будет встретиться* — тоже простое предложение.

В Нацкорпусе после "это значит", если дальше есть "надо", стоит знак (запятая/тире/двоеточие): [**примеры**](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&api=1.0&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&mydocsize=&mode=main&lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&nodia=1&text=lexgramm&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE&gramm1=&sem1=&flags1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82&gramm2=&sem2=&flags2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&parent3=0&level3=0&min3=1&max3=8&lex3=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE&gramm3=&sem3=&flags3=&sem-mod3=sem&sem-mod3=sem2).

Answer (score 1):

С давних времен помню правило о слове "значит". Если оно употребляется в значении "означает", то является частью сказуемого и не выделяется запятыми ("Любить - это значит в глубь двора вбежать и до ночи грачьей, блестя топором, рубить дрова, силой своей играючи..." (В. Маяковский). Если же слово "значит" употребляется в смысле "следовательно", то это вводное слово. В Вашем предложении слово "значит" употреблено в значении "означает", следовательно, запятая не нужна

Comment: Найдите хоть один пример, где не только инфинитив (здесь + "надо будет").

Comment: Из книги Владимира Песни «Седой»:  _Просто так в поезд нас не посадят, паспортов нет, а **это значит надо будет искать** товарняк, **прыгать** в него и **ехать**, пока не прогонят!_

Comment: @slava1947 Надо что-то поавторитетнее. В Нацкорпусе в таких случаях стоит какой-то знак: https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?dpp=10&format=html&g=i_doc&kwsz=5&lang=ru&mode=main&nodia=1&out=normal&req=это+значит+надо&sampling=1&sort=i_grtagging&spd=10&spp=50&sr=1&text=lexform

Answer (score 0):

Запятая нужна, она ставится и при пропуске "что". Так и наоборот: если можно вставить "что", то запятая ставится.

Чтобы не было запятой, нужны кавычки:
Это значит "завтра пораньше надо будет встретиться".
Но такая структура не подходит, потому что фразу в кавычках можно изменить. Кавычки используются при цитировании (точная передача слов).
Но вот пример:
*Это значит "попасться навстречу или в поле зрения; оказаться на чьём-либо пути".*

Comment: Я вычитал из "Правил постановке тире", что в ряде случаев перед сказуемым (предикатом) используются связки "это значит", "это когда", "это есть". Разве если это связки, нужно ставить запятую?

Comment: После "это когда", "это есть" не нужно, а после "это значит" нужно. Можно ссылку на эти правила? Тогда разберёмся, в чём там дело. Может, там что-то другое имеется в виду.

Comment: Может, это? http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=672

Comment: Уже даже знаю, в чём дело. Правило: Тире ставится при выражении и подлежащего, и сказуемого (или только подлежащего, или только сказуемого) **инфинитивом**. Это так: *Это значит завтра пораньше встретиться.* Сюда уже "что" не подставляется. Два слова пришлось убрать, они превращают предложение в сложное, из-за чего нужна запятая.

Comment: Если присоединяете связкой простое предложение (они могут существовать без "это значит"), запятая нужна.

Answer (score 0):

**Внутри простого предложения между подлежащим и сказуемым:**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]